# Selenium not checking box

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, click

Trying to get selenium to check a box with python but it seems to keep timing out.

Current code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://grabagun.com/giveaway')

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="terms_and_conditions"]'))).click()
```

The error is:

```
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //*[@id="terms_and_conditions" because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id="terms_and_conditions"' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the html code of the web page?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use action chains and the correct lookup:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "terms_and_conditions")

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
```